# how to retrieve an array from php function?

Tags: php, arrays, function

i get list of students from database in array and return it with function:

```
class StudentClass
{
    public function getAllStudent()
    {
        $host = "localhost";
        $database = "mms_db";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dns = "mysql:host=$host; dbname=$database";
        $connect = new PDO($dns, $username, $password);
        $connect->query("set names utf8");
        $connect->query("set charset utf8");
        $sql = "select * from students";
        $result = $connect->prepare($sql);
        $result->execute();
        $starraye = $result->fetchAll();
        return $starraye;
    }
}
```

now i want to retrieve this array and echo with foreach():

```
<?php
    include ("StudentClass.php");
    $student_object = new StudentClass();
    $student_object->getAllStudent();
    foreach ($starraye as $rows)
    {
        echo $rows['fname'];
    }
```

but i get error:

[image]

tanks!

Comment: you need to store the returned array.

Comment: you need to store the return value `$starraye = $student_object->getAllStudent();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the return array, After a function call you have to store the return data in any variable. You did't make it so the error shows up.

```
include ("StudentClass.php");
$student_object = new StudentClass();
$starraye = $student_object->getAllStudent(); //store here
foreach ($starraye as $rows)
{
    echo $rows['fname'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Function **getAllStudent** is returning data as array so you have to store the return array in some variable and you can use that variable...

So Use it like

```
$output_array = $student_object->getAllStudent();
if($output_array!= false)
{
    foreach ($output_array as $rows)
    {
        echo $rows['fname'];
    }
}
```